# Not same result in csv as in terminal. Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

In terminal when I compare two list, in terminal I got 67 4 6 in a column and in csv just a 6.

```
import csv

s1=[4,6,0,23,8,67,5]
s2=[2,3,9,6,7,67,4]
a=list(set(s1)&set(s2))

for q in a:
    print(q)
f = open('fm/state/csv/test', 'w')
f.write (str(q))
```

Comment: You are only writing the LAST element of `a` since your write is out of the loop!

Comment: you write down f.write only q. and what is q? somehow you don't used to Python and for loop yet put the f.write in for

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('fm/state/csv/test', 'w')
for q in a:
    print(q)
    f.write (str(q))

# u should write data in for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code, write to csv common numbers as list to csv file:

```
import csv

s1=[4,6,0,23,8,67,5]
s2=[2,3,9,6,7,67,4,]
a=list(set(s1)&set(s2))

with open('/fm/state/csv/test', 'w') as f:
  f.write (str(a))
```